# How To Include DCMTK to IOS Projest

Tags: ios, ios7, dcmtk

I successfully compiled `DCMTK` for `IOS7` and got all libraries and All other files. By using these file I tried to create a sample App  http://www.cppblog.com/kesalin/archive/2011/11/10/dcmtk_ios.html

I got some idea from this. But now I'm stuck in following error.

```
**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_DIMSE_BADCOMMANDTYPE", referenced from:
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
  "_DIMSE_BADDATA", referenced from:
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
  "_DIMSE_NODATAAVAILABLE", referenced from:
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
  "_DIMSE_NOVALIDPRESENTATIONCONTEXTID", referenced from:
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
  "_DUL_ASSOCIATIONREJECTED", referenced from:
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
  "_DUL_PEERABORTEDASSOCIATION", referenced from:
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
  "_DUL_PEERREQUESTEDRELEASE", referenced from:
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
  "_EC_Normal", referenced from:
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      applyOverrideKeys(DcmDataset*) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      addOverrideKey(OFConsoleApplication&, char const*) in movescu.o
      cmove(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
      moveCallback(void*, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRQ*, int, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRSP*) in movescu.o
      ...
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      applyOverrideKeys(DcmDataset*) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      addOverrideKey(OFConsoleApplication&, char const*) in movescu.o
      cmove(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
      moveCallback(void*, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRQ*, int, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRSP*) in movescu.o
      ...
  "DIMSE_moveUser(T_ASC_Association*, unsigned char, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRQ*, DcmDataset*, void (*)(void*, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRQ*, int, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRSP*), void*, T_DIMSE_BlockingMode, int, T_ASC_Network*, void (*)(void*, T_ASC_Network*, T_ASC_Association**), void*, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRSP*, DcmDataset**, DcmDataset**, bool)", referenced from:
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
  "ASC_dataWaiting(T_ASC_Association*, int)", referenced from:
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
  "ASC_dropNetwork(T_ASC_Network**)", referenced from:
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
  "ASC_getAPTitles(T_ASC_Parameters*, char*, char*, char*)", referenced from:
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
  "ASC_setAPTitles(T_ASC_Parameters*, char const*, char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
  "newDicomElement(DcmTag const&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      addOverrideKey(OFConsoleApplication&, char const*) in movescu.o
  "DIMSE_dumpMessage(OFString&, T_DIMSE_C_EchoRQ&, DIMSE_direction, DcmItem*, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      echoSCP(T_ASC_Association*, T_DIMSE_Message*, unsigned char) in movescu.o
  "DIMSE_dumpMessage(OFString&, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRSP&, DIMSE_direction, DcmItem*, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      moveSCU(T_ASC_Association*, char const*) in movescu.o
      moveCallback(void*, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRQ*, int, T_DIMSE_C_MoveRSP*) in movescu.o
  "DIMSE_dumpMessage(OFString&, T_DIMSE_C_StoreRQ&, DIMSE_direction, DcmItem*, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      storeSCP(T_ASC_Association*, T_DIMSE_Message*, unsigned char) in movescu.o
  "ASC_dumpParameters(OFString&, T_ASC_Parameters*, ASC_associateType)", referenced from:
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
  "prepareCmdLineArgs(int&, char**, char const*)", referenced from:
      getfileusinggetscu(int, char**) in getscu.o
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
  "ASC_dropAssociation(T_ASC_Association*)", referenced from:
      acceptSubAssoc(T_ASC_Network*, T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
  "DIMSE_storeProvider(T_ASC_Association*, unsigned char, T_DIMSE_C_StoreRQ*, char const*, int, DcmDataset**, void (*)(void*, T_DIMSE_StoreProgress*, T_DIMSE_C_StoreRQ*, char*, DcmDataset**, T_DIMSE_C_StoreRSP*, DcmDataset**), void*, T_DIMSE_BlockingMode, int)", referenced from:
      storeSCP(T_ASC_Association*, T_DIMSE_Message*, unsigned char) in movescu.o
  "ASC_abortAssociation(T_ASC_Association*)", referenced from:
      retrievefile(int, char**) in movescu.o
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o
      storeSCPCallback(void*, T_DIMSE_StoreProgress*, T_DIMSE_C_StoreRQ*, char*, DcmDataset**, T_DIMSE_C_StoreRSP*, DcmDataset**) in movescu.o
  "DIMSE_receiveCommand(T_ASC_Association*, T_DIMSE_BlockingMode, int, unsigned char*, T_DIMSE_Message*, DcmDataset**, DcmDataset**)", referenced from:
      subOpSCP(T_ASC_Association**) in movescu.o**
```

Comment: @mehdi,Thanks for editing.I'm new to stackoverflow.Do you have any idea how to do it..or what's my error

Comment: OK,I fixed the problem,it was a problem with the Search path for library and Header Files.